# Windows 10 reboots without blue screen or crash dump

Tags: windows-10, memory, bsod, crash

**UPDATE: Eight and a half months later,** the problem persists, but now happens every time a VM is started, whether from BlueStacks, Vagrant, or just starting up from the VirtualBox console.  The stop code varies. Over the last few times I've gotten:

- APC_INDEX_MISMATCH
- DRIVER_OVERRAN_STACK_BUFFER
- INTERRUPT_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
- SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
- 0x00000133
- KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
- 0x00000109
- DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
- IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

I've run numerous memory scans, the vast majority of which show no problems. Two have run into "unspecified" errors, and one many months ago generated a blue screen with no stop code.  Nothing where I could identify a stick that is problematic.

VirtualBox is up to date, all drivers are up to date.

I guess I could go buy a whole new set of memory and give it a try, but that sounds like a potential waste of money.

Current Windows build: Version 1703, build 15063.540

---

**ORIGINAL ENTRY:**
For the past couple of weeks, my computer has occasionally rebooted for no apparent reason (i.e. No BSOD, no crash dump left behind, no entries in Event Log beyond the one entry for Kernel-Power, Event 41 ("The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first...").

I'm thinking motherboard, or power supply?? Memory problems probably should leave some sort of trail, right?

My setup: Dell XPS 8700, i7-4770, BIOS Dell A11, 12GB memory,  OS= Win10 Pro build 14393.

Three weeks ago my HD died, and I replaced it with a WD Blue, 2TB.

I have been using VirtualBox more lately to run Ubuntu/WinXP/Win7.

Any suggestions?

---

edit:  The last two reboots have event data in the Event 41: one had IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL in hal.dll; the other had CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT in ntoskrnl.exe.

---

Update: the reboots have continued, on a not so regular basis. Some have had event data, others haven't. Most occurred some time after a VM was spun up, though a couple happened during sessions that had no VM.

So, I'm now going on the idea that it is bad memory, and am now running some tests.  I will update how that goes.

---

**UPDATE: 1-17-2017** 
same description as above, now on Windows build 14393.693.  I should also add that mine is a dual monitor setup, 24" dell s2409w monitor as primary,  and a Samsung SyncMaster 192n.  When the reboots occur, the Samsung goes blank, the system goes unresponsive, and depending on whether a crashdump is saved or not, does a power-down reboot in either 10 seconds, or whenever the crashdump is finished saving.  There is no actual "blue screen" happening.

This time, here is a list of incidents from BlueScreenView.  Note that there are still a few reboots that didn't produce a crash dump, but I'd say that's < 10% of reboots.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1x2WV9ycscCm41s_b6EybhPrqMCU2MouWKMRHwJYcXhA/edit?usp=sharing

Since there was a recent crash attributed to the video card (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 645) I just upgraded that driver (was from 1/2016, now 9/2016), so I'll see what effect that has.

---

Update an hour later: well that didn't matter.  Rebooted again first session after the upgrade.

> `==================================================`
>   `Dump File         : 011717-66281-01.dmp`
>   `Crash Time        : 1/17/2017 3:10:50 PM`
>   `Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT`
>   `Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a`
>   `Parameter 1       : 00000000 00061941`
>   `Parameter 2       : ffffcd0e 9cf4563a`
>   `Parameter 3       : 00000000 00000009`
>   `Parameter 4       : ffffaa00 826d4750`
>   `Caused By Driver  : hal.dll`
>   `Caused By Address : hal.dll+387f`
>   `Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+14a6f0`
>   `File Description  : Hardware Abstraction Layer DLL`
>   `Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System`
>   `Company           : Microsoft Corporation`
>   `File Version      : 10.0.14393.206 (rs1_release.160915-0644)`
>   `Processor         : x64`
>   `Full Path         : C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\011717-66281-01.dmp`
>   `Processors Count  : 8`
>   `Major Version     : 15`
>   `Minor Version     : 14393`
>   `Dump File Size    : 506,820`
>   `Dump File Time    : 1/17/2017 3:14:47 PM`
>   `==================================================`

Same error as the NVIDIA crash a couple of days ago, but doesn't seem to involve the NVIDIA.

Comment: Could also be an issue with line power itself. Do you have the system on a UPS? Is the BIOS set to automatically power the system back on after power loss?

Comment: I would first start with the PSU.

Comment: It could be a power source or PSU issue, but most commonly this could be caused by CPU overheat which would make sense if you've increased the CPU load with a VM.  Monitor the CPU temperature to verify that possibility.

Comment: Buggy drivers can also cause unintended restarts, these are hard to solve as there is no trail left when this happens.

Comment: CPU temp averaging 45c, GPU temp 34c.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028504

Comment: Have you figured out what it was?

Answer (score 0):

It could mean there is also a problem with a windows system file. Easy way to check its not a windows system file is to run command prompt. and type SFC /SCANNOW

the other thing you could try doing, is creating a custom view in the event viewer and attach any event collectors you think might hold the information you are looking for and wait for it to happen again, then check your custom event view. You can add an event logger to just about anything that your OS has installed to hardware plugged in. And to just give you and idead what you can do with event viewer of how powerful it is, you can even make custom tasks run based off when certain events happen, given the event is loggable.

As some have said, it is possible it is a bad driver, the common one of these drivers to cause your computer to reboot is a bad graphics driver. However, any bad driver can cause your computer to restart. Also, if the inside of your computer is dirty, it can cause it to shutdown because something shorts out or some other component gets too hot and thus not working right because of it.

So to help you resolve this, the best thing to do in this type of situation is to start at the basics by first physically cleaning your computer and then cleaning the up junk inside the OS. From removing old programs, emptying the recycle bin, defrag the computer install windows updates if there is any and the last, go research to see if there is updated drivers for hardware you have in your computer. Such as graphics driver, network card drivers, audio drivers, etc. If there was problems with your hardware like the memory or harddrive the OS would have detected it and logged it somewhere before the system crashes or in your case just reboots. As you can see without further information, it can be a number of things, but if you do some of these maintenance tasks you will at least be able to eliminate more things off your list as to what is possibly causing it.